# Same element on Different page shows different CSS

Tags: css, background, transparency

The Service page does not show the same transparency as pages that use the same element. How do I correct this?

---

[Service Page](https://www.ladnerspools.com/request-service-2/)

---

[Contact Page](https://www.ladnerspools.com/contact/)

---

```
.bgs-page {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow:  0 15px 15px 12px     rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.7);
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Optical illusion? Looks the same to me... and inspecting the DOM the styles are the same as well.

Comment: Could it have something to do with Wordpress? I flush the cache regularly. Just noticed it changes with the width of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like the problem is adding the class `bgs-post-page` and `bgs-page` on a div that is nested within a div with the class of `bgs-page`.

On the contact page remove both of those classes mentioned above from the div with these classes `col-md-12 bgs-page bgs-post-page post-111 page type-page status-publish hentry` and the problem will go away with the background issue.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue.